# Determine when to send push notifications on expo with HTTP/2 API

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-push-notification

I am trying to build a water reminder app. I have 3 screens and I am using react-navigation

- Home (that I allow users to increase their amount drink that day)
- Notifications (where users defining with switch buttons if they want
  to receive notifications and when to receive)
- Settings (where user enters age, weight to determine how much they should drink daily). this is the first screen users see when they downloaded the app

I am trying to send a push notifications to my users with using expo push notifications and their HTTP/2 API. But I am kinda lost on this and have those questions below.

1. Where to write push notifications code below and call HTTP/2 API? (App.js, notifications or settings?)
2. How can I determine when to send this notifications such as for every hour based on users selection.

My code for getting permission, store key and call api to send notifications.

```
    registerforPushNotifications = async () => {
    // check fox existing permission
    const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = status;

    // if no existing permission granted ask user
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }

    //if no permission is granted exit the status
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }

    // get the token
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

    const request = {
      to: token,
      title: "Don't forget to drink water",
    };

    _storeToken = async () => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token.toString());
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };

    _storeToken();

    return fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'host':'exp.host',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
    }).then(data => {console.log(data)});
  };
```

response that I receive

```
"_bodyInit": "{\"data\":{\"status\":\"ok\",\"id\":\"93d0f654-d8f6-4587-b4bb-ed4f5cd08b68\"}}",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using firebase, I have decided to use

> Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification,
>   schedulingOptions)

This helps me to schedule a local notification to fire at some specific time in the future or at a given interval.

**Arguments**

**localNotification (object)** -- An object with the properties described in LocalNotification.

**schedulingOptions (object)** -- An object that describes when the notification should fire.

- **time (date or number)** -- A Date object representing when to fire the
  notification or a number in Unix epoch time. Example: (new
  Date()).getTime() + 1000 is one second from now.
- **repeat (optional) (string)** -- 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week',
  'month', or 'year'.
- **(Android only) intervalMs (optional) (number)** -- Repeat interval in
  number of milliseconds

  componentDidMount() {
      this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {

  ```
    // call the functions after component did mounted
    this._handleLocalNotification();
    this.listenForNotifications();
  });}

  // function to request permission to send notifications and schedule notifications
  _handleLocalNotification = async () => {
  // check fox existing permission
  const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
  let finalStatus = status;

  // if no existing permission granted ask user
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  //if no permission is granted exit the status
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }

  const localnotification = {
    title: 'Water Reminder',
    body: 'Dont forget to drink water!',
    android: {
      sound: true,
    },
    ios: {
      sound: true,
    },
  };
  let sendAfterFiveSeconds = Date.now();
  sendAfterFiveSeconds += 5000;

  const schedulingOptions = { time: sendAfterFiveSeconds };
  Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localnotification, schedulingOptions);
    };
  ```

  // function to listen if notification received while the app is open. When it receive, it will create and alert

```
      listenForNotifications = () => {
        Notifications.addListener(notification => {
          if (notification.origin === 'received') {
            Alert.alert(localnotification.title, localnotification.body);
          }
        });
      };
```

Comment: kudos to well written question and answer